# Click tools with optional arguments

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I want to write a CLI *hello* that takes a FILENAME as an argument except when the option -s STRING is given, in which case the STRING is processed directly. The program should print `hello {NAME}` where name is either given via the STRING or taken to be the contents of the file FILENAME.

*example*:

```
$ cat myname.txt
john

$ hello myname.txt
hello john

$ hello -s paul
hello paul
```

A possible workaround is to use two options:

```py
@click.command()
@click.option("-f", "--filename", type=str)
@click.option("-s", "--string", type=str)
def main(filename: str, string: str):
    if filename:
        ...
    if string:
        ....
```

but that means that I must call `hello` with a flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Click [argument](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/arguments/) and make it not required like:

```
import click
@click.command()
@click.argument('filename', required=False)
@click.option("-s", "--string")
def main(filename, string):
    if None not in (filename, string):
        raise click.ClickException('filename argument and option string are mutually exclusive!')
    click.echo(f'Filename: {filename}')
    click.echo(f'String: {string}')
```

Comment: Quick question for clarification: you could use `argument` for both options in the given case, right?

Comment: @self Only now I figured out that I misunderstood your suggestion. I thought `argument('some')` would be a shortcut for `option('-s', '--some',tyle=str)`: **of course not both** can be made an optional argument! Maybe the short introduction can be too short for people new to the Click API. ... the approach shown in the code leads to a good CLI.